# Can I temporarly disable automatic login while booting?

Tags: macos, startup, login

Is there a key to press in order to disable automatic login for that single boot?

I do not want to disable automatic login entirely, I wonder if there is a key combination that, if you keep it pressed while booting, OSX will not automatically login *that time only*.

---

Current answer is tuned for a previous version of OSX (<10.6), and it should be "upgraded" to 10.10.

Comment: And the -1 was dumbly awarded because...?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to press and hold the Shift key during the boot ONLY when the Blue screen appears. It will disable autologin and you can choose between your accounts.

Comment: Loading screen is no longer blue (it was blue in 10.3 IIRC?), but except this little detail, it worked! : )

Comment: glad I could help.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not as easy as it looks. Currently I've no clue on how to pick the right moment to hit shift, and after managing to make it work twice after this answer was posted, I never managed it again since. Hence, I have to unaccept the answer.